# Como Puedo detectar varios objectos dentro de un collider con el mismo tag ?? Unity 5 C#

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un codigo donde a través de un sphere collider me detecte barios gameobjects con el mismo tag , pero solo me detecta uno como puedo hacerle para que me detecte todos los que estan dentro ???

Gracias.

Comment: Coloca el codigo que has probado para que puedan ayudarte.

Comment: Pues es un simple OnTriggerEnter , pero solo me detecta el primer objeto que entra los demas ya no me los detecta , todos tiene el mismo tag.

Comment: Te van a votar de forma negativa la pregunta.